# How to Read Multiple Location sections from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my web confi file I have different locations like this

```
<location path="path1">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="15000"/>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="path2">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="15000"/>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I've tried with

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("location")
```

but this returns null
Help me to get all location sections and read each execution timeout within the location

Comment: That's not how the [location](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-location-element-demystified/) element works with ConfigurationManager.  You'll need to read the XML file into a XML parser, like XDocument of XmlDocument and query the data through that API.

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? The `<location>` tag is for providing overrides or additional config at a specific folder level; what are you trying to do with the element itself ?